# Coding a Non-Rectangle Healthbar

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a game, and the health bar is done in flash using actionscript.

If the bar was just rectangle, I would be able to do this easily, but it is of an irregular shape and do not know how to.

e.g https://i.stack.imgur.com/20J8a.png (Badly drawn)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the flash ide, you could just create a movieclip using a mask. Or you can always draw it purely in code based on the value.

Comment: you can try having the actual display in a movieclip with a different frame for each health bar. store the health internally and update the frame according to the health

Comment: Masking via code is also possible, use `mask` property for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask` property to create a visible moving border over an object of irregular shape. An example:

```
class HealthBar extends Sprite {
    // implement normal healthbar draw, any shape allowed
    var m:Sprite;
    function HealthBar() {
        m=new Sprite();
        m.graphics.beginFill(0x0,1);
        m.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,50); // make sure it overlaps whole healthbar
        m.graphics.endFill();
        this.mask=m; // to set mask
        addChild(m); // necessary, otherwise it might not work properly
    }
    function adjustHealthBar(percentage:int):void {
        // will be called when you need to change the display
        // 0 = empty, 100 = full
        m.x=0-m.width*percentage/100; 
        // shift mask leftwards, so less of bar is visible
        // that's all! If you need fancy, redraw graphics of "m" for new healthbar state
    }
}
```